# How to determine what bitmap resource was loaded (ldpi, mdpi, or hdpi)?

Tags: android, screen, resolution, dpi

I have created multiple bitmaps - one for each folder (mdpi, hdpi, ldpi). Can someone show me some code or point me to the appropriate method that will allow me to detect which resource Android decided to load.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is available in the bitmap itself -- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#getDensity()

If you are loading this through the higher level Resources.getDrawable() API, you won't have a Bitmap but just an abstract Drawable.  If you can guarantee the resource will always be a bitmap (not a nine patch or other such thing), you can cast this to a BitmapDrawable and get the Bitmap from that.

If you are doing this for production code, I would be a little uncomfortable with this since generally an app should either let the framework take care of density, or take care of it all itself (by for example putting the bitmaps in drawable-nodpi).  If you are playing games with bitmaps base on loaded density, you may shoot yourself in the foot.  Or you may be fine, since I don't really know what you are doing. :)

Comment: Thanks. I am loading through getResources(), R.drawable and it will always be a bitmap. If this ends up in prod is yet to be determined. Depends on what I learn before then. If the framework always picks the correct density, I won't have to do as much, but I didn't want to assume it was bug free, so I wanted to verify it picked what I expected based screen dimensions. If it didn't, I'll scale it myself and set some values, so I can calculate locations of the bitmaps on the screen. There are some other reasons I want this info, but I am running out of characters that I can type in this comment.

Comment: You wouldn't want to scale it yourself -- the framework will automatically scale a drawable (including the dimensions reported to you) based on the density of its bitmap in relation to the device (or target Canvas) density.  There are a lot of subtle things done to ensure that a drawable in a density different than the density the app is working in will behave as if it is in the app's density.  This is fundamental to things like the density compatibility code that ensures applications written before 1.6 still work on device with different density screens.

Comment: One of the reasons I thought about doing this is when I had a background bitmap that was 480 x 800 and I tested it on a 480 x 854 display, there was a gap at the bottom. In other words, it didn't scale it automatically to that screen. As soon, as I put code in to scale it myself, it looked fine. Are you saying it was supposed to scale automatically to the 480 x 854 screen?

Comment: hackbod, I thought about what you said - maybe I am doing something more fundamentally wrong. I think I will post another question and ask a more fundamental question about dpi and scaling.

Comment: I did some testing and now I know what I had a misconception about. I was was putting background bitmaps designed to take up a full screen in the dpi directories. I had thought a 240dpi bitmap made for a 480 x 800 screen would then be scaled by the framework to fit a 240dpi screen with a 480 x 854 resolution. Now I understand that those directories don't do any scaling. It seems they are really for you to put images in that you pre-scale such as custom buttons or spacecraft or other small images. They are not for backgrounds, since those do need to be scaled to the screen resolution.

Comment: Thanks again for your comments. It made me think this through better and understand the overall framework better. I still need to be able to find out the exact width and height of loaded bitmaps, so I can calculate where to put them without overlapping images they shouldn't - but I think know how to do that now based on the feedback I got from others in this thread. Thanks again and thank you everyone else who responded.

Answer (score 4):

Get the densityDPI from DisplayMetric and check it against predefined constants

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

switch(metrics.densityDpi)
{
case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH: //HDPI
case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:  //LDPI
case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM: //MDPI
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. I tried it out within onSizeChanged within my view and it flags it as an error "getWindowManger() is undefined in type GameView" where GameView is my custom view for drawing my bitmaps on the canvas, handling touch events, etc... I get NO errors, if I put it within my Activity that launches this view.. I was planning on doing it within onSizeChanged, so I can set some flags to change the way I draw the bitmaps, deal touchevents and draw on the bitmaps based on which bitmap was loaded. But, I guess I'll just set the flags within the parent activity instead.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what can do with code but for testing purposes I added a small icon called resolution.png that had a version in the ldpi which had the letter 'l' in it, the version for mdpi had a letter 'm' in it and the version for hdpi had the letter 'h' in it.  That way you can see which version of the resources are being loaded.

I test with it commented out in the layout most of the time and un-comment it when I want to investigate.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. That will help with testing.

Answer (score 0):

Load a Bitmap directly and compare it with the one loaded via resources:

Resources can be accessed as raw data: use [AssetManager.open(..)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html#open%28java.lang.String%29)
Then you can use [BitmapFactory.decodeStream(..)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeStream%28java.io.InputStream%29) to create a Bitmap from the data stream.